# Recursion with two results

Tags: recursion, f#

I have built a function that recursively calculate the progressive powers of two, up to a certain value `n`.

```
let rec aux_pow =
fun e n -> 
    match n with
    | n         ->  1        # I tried with e, but clearly it modifies the result
    | _         ->  2 * aux_pow (e + 1) n
```

The function will return an integer (2, 4, 8, 16 ... n), that can be used by other functions as parameter etc... . Easy. What I am looking for, is a way to return also the value of `e`, that is, the grade of the power. Is it actually possible? I know that each function can return only a value. What is the best way to get both the **result** of the recursion and, in this case, the **number** of recursion cycles?

I.e. for `aux_pow 0 8` how can I have the value of `e` that is equal to `3` and at the same time making the function return the result of `2 * 2 * 2 = 8`? Is it possible? Is it a meaningless problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to return 2 values from a function is to use [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/tuples). I took some liberties with the sample code you provided and came up with a version that should do what you're looking for.

```
let aux_pow limit =
  let rec aux_pow' value counter =
    match value with
    | n when n = limit -> (limit, counter)
    | n when n > limit -> (int (2. ** double (counter - 1)), counter - 1)
    | _ -> aux_pow' (2 * value) (counter + 1)

  aux_pow' 1 0
```

It defines an internal recursive function that keeps count of the number of times it is run. The output is a tuple with the value and the count.

It also contains a case when a non-power-of-2 value is specified for the limit.